# Boto3 Glue client create_job() module path error `ModuleNotFoundError`

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue, import-module

I'm trying to use boto3 client `create_job()` to create a Glue job, this is the script:

```
job = client.create_job(Name=xxx,
                        Role=xxx,
                        Command={
                           'Name': 'glueetl',
                           'ScriptLocation': 's3://my_bucket_name/my_project_name/src/glue.py',
                           'PythonVersion': '3'},
                        DefaultArguments={
                           '--job-language': 'python',
                           '--extra-py-files': 's3://my_bucket_name/my_project_name/src/test.zip',
                           '--conf': 'spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=7g --conf spark.jars.packages=xxx',
                                },
                        ExecutionProperty={
                           'MaxConcurrentRuns': 1
                                },
                        GlueVersion='1.0'
                        )
```

The structure in `test.zip` is `__init__.py` file + 'glue.py' file (which is duplicated with the one specified in `ScriptLocation`) + `example.py`

Inside the 'glue.py' I have `import example`, then the job failed with error `"ErrorMessage":"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'example\'"`.

I tried `from test import example` but not working, I'm confused and stuck here, how Glue read and import modules? do I need to setup something? Might someone be able to help please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `_init_.py` is **incorrect**. It should be `__init__.py` (double underscore) as explained in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html#aws-glue-programming-python-libraries-zipping).

Comment: Hi that's a typo, sorry for the confusion, I do have  `__init__.py` (double underscore).

Comment: @Cecilia Can you provide example of your `test.zip` and `glue.py`?